# Two RCP Applications in one installation

Tags: build, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I recenty developed an Eclipse RCP application based on an existing RCP application. It´s basically used as a url protocol handler which reuses authentication and some services. I´m trying to avoid a second installation and look for a way to integrate the new RCP application into the installation of the existing RCP - is there a way to achieve this?

I´m (still) using Eclipse 3.8 and build with tycho.

Comment: Yeah, sure... It´s two applications that share a lot of plug-ins - that´s why I want to avoid two seperate installations. And I´m also looking for something more simple than the p2 shared installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have multiple [applications](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_core_runtime_applications.html&cp=2_1_1_28) within your product, you can launch the desired one using the

> -application `id`

runtime argument.

Comment: Yes, I will do it that way, thx! If you see any possiblity to build to "exe"´s for each application in one build - let me know. One application will be used as a protocol handler in the windows registry where it´s always easier to use exe´s...

Comment: This depends on how you package your product.

Using NSIS (i'm assuming windows since you mention the registry), you can create an .exe, which is just a shortcut to the main .exe.

For example:
`nsExec::Exec '${INST_PATH}\${APP_NAME}\${MAIN_APP_EXE} -application <app_id>'`

Answer (score 0):

In our application, which integrates multiple Eclipse RCP applications, we have a custom target platform, which bundles all other application plugins, so everything is shipped together. Also, all artifacts, provided by other applications can be retrieved from the maven repository, so that necessary services may be added as a dependencies to, for instance, server side projects. Hope that helps.